# How to split only the numbers and/or words from a string into an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have the string `"1, 2, 3"` and the string `"1, 2, 3 Go!"` I would like to split into an array that only includes the numbers or the words without the punctuation.

So first one becomes `["1", "2", "3"]`

The second one becomes `["1","2","3", "Go"]`

I can get the first one by `"1, 2, 3".split(/[^0-9]/).filter(function(value){if(value) return value;}`

I use `filter` because I get `["1", "", "2", "", "3"]` when I just use `split`.

I don't know who to get the second array.

Is there a regular expression pattern that will only split the string into either numbers and or words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
"1, 2, 3 Go!".match(/\d+|[a-zA-Z]+/g) //outputs ["1", "2", "3", "Go"]
```